# tax exemption for a partner when one is working abroad all year long but other one stays in US

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-exemption

I have a green card and a US employer who could pay me abroad since we have offices in the EU and Asia. I have been working from these offices in EU and Asia for the past 6 months and came back a week ago.

My wife and I file a joint income tax. But, She stays in the US all year long. What are my chances of getting tax exemption?

Comment: As a green-card holder you remain subject to US tax no matter where you are. However, as either citizen _or_ green-card if you live and work in a foreign country (and not for the US government) full-time or very close to it, you can _exclude_ your foreign earned income and possibly housing up to a limit currently $105,900 from US tax; see [pub 54 chapter 4](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p54#idm140043241757488). Your other income remains subject to US tax, although if it is also subject to foreign tax your US tax can be reduced by the Foreign Tax Credit, also in that pub. ...

Comment: ... If you are living in another country you will likely want to have a bank account there, so remember that as a US tax resident if you own or control foreign bank account(s) over $10k you must _report_ it(them) on FBAR.